# Running Grunt Build does not compile jade files

Tags: yeoman, grunt-contrib-jade

I implemented Jade template engine, Yeoman-AngularJS app, it is working fine on my local.

But when deploying it, running `Grunt Build` does not compile .jade files. 
That's why I am getting an error `Cannot GET /` on production.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the output folder if the html files are being correctly generated.
You can see in the grunt file the destination folder (in my case .tmp) and the specific options. Perhaps the src rule is not matching your source file.

```
    // Compiles Jade to html
jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      data: {
        debug: false
      }
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
      src: [
        '{app,components}/**/*.jade'
      ],
      dest: '.tmp',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
},
```